# Generate multipage PDF from NSAttributedString swift 3

Tags: ios, pdf, swift3

I have a pretty long `NSAttributedString` that i'm trying to draw to PDF, making a single page PDF was pretty simple with the draw func:

```
func createPDFFilea(atext: NSAttributedString) -> NSMutableData {

    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    let paperRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, paperRect, nil)
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()

    atext.draw(in: paperRect)
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

    return pdfData
}
```

but if the text exceed the `paperRect` it will be lost, how to manage this?

PS. here a similar solution with a simple `NSString` for obj-C 
http://www.coderzheaven.com/2016/09/07/create-pdf-in-ios/
but i cannot figure out to get it in Swift and seems also official apple doc are only for obj-C
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html

Comment: I have recently had to do the same sort of thing - I have a multi-section table to print, which may split over multiple pages.  My solution was to add one row at a time to a UIWebView, and use the 'webViewDidFinishLoad' to check the page size - once it exceeded a page I use the previous html text, and create a new UIWebView.  Once all of the web pages were complete, it's a simple task to create a multi-page PDF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i've finally managed to convert the obj-C code to swift3

```
    func createPDFwithAttributedString(_ currentText: NSAttributedString) -> NSMutableData {

    let pdfData = NSMutableData()

    // Create the PDF context using the default page size of 612 x 792.
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect.zero, nil)

    let framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(currentText)

    var currentRange = CFRangeMake(0, 0);
    var currentPage = 0;
    var done = false;

    repeat {
        // Mark the beginning of a new page.
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 612, height: 792), nil);

        // Draw a page number at the bottom of each page.
        currentPage += 1;

        // Render the current page and update the current range to
        // point to the beginning of the next page.
        renderPagewithTextRange(currentRange: &currentRange, framesetter: framesetter)

        // If we're at the end of the text, exit the loop.
        if (currentRange.location == CFAttributedStringGetLength(currentText)){
            done = true;
        }
    } while (!done);

    // Close the PDF context and write the contents out.
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
    return pdfData
}

func renderPagewithTextRange (currentRange: inout CFRange,  framesetter: CTFramesetter) {
    // Get the graphics context.
    if let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(){

        // Put the text matrix into a known state. This ensures
        // that no old scaling factors are left in place.
        currentContext.textMatrix = CGAffineTransform.identity;

        // Create a path object to enclose the text. Use 72 point
        // margins all around the text.
        let frameRect = CGRect(x: 72, y: 72, width: 468, height: 648);
        let framePath = CGMutablePath();
        framePath.addRect(frameRect)

        // Get the frame that will do the rendering.
        // The currentRange variable specifies only the starting point. The framesetter
        // lays out as much text as will fit into the frame.
        let frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, currentRange, framePath, nil);

        // Core Text draws from the bottom-left corner up, so flip
        // the current transform prior to drawing.
        currentContext.translateBy(x: 0, y: 792);
        currentContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0);

        // Draw the frame.
        CTFrameDraw(frameRef, currentContext);

        // Update the current range based on what was drawn.
        currentRange = CTFrameGetVisibleStringRange(frameRef);
        currentRange.location += currentRange.length;
        currentRange.length = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only issue with this is does not support NSTextAttachment Images in an NSAttributedString for some reason